# Getting the instance of a class decorated function

Tags: python, function, class, object, decorator

I have a class as follows:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper():
            print("decorated", self.x, self.y)
            func()
        return wrapper
```

Now if I want to use this class to decorate functions:

```py
@A(4, 5)
def fn():
  print("original function")

fn()
```

Output:

```
decorated 4 5
original function
```

Questions:

1. Since in `@A(3, 4)` the `__init__` class constructor is called, where did the created instance of class `A` go? Is there a way to reference it?
2. How can I access the properties `self.x, self.y` outside of the class, without calling `fn()`?
   (I want something like `fn.x` or `fn.y`, but they don't work)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `__closure__` to get a tuple of `cell` objects.

In this case the first element is a cell object for the function and the second is the cell object for the class `A`.

You can access that using `f.__closure__[1]` and get the object using `.cell_contents`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper():
            print("decorated", self.x, self.y)
            func()
        return wrapper

@A(1, 2)
def f():
    print('fun')


A_cell = f.__closure__[1]

A_obj = A_cell.cell_contents

print(A_obj.x, A_obj.y) # 1 2
```

To answer your questions

1. Is there a way to reference the created instance of class `A`? Yes, `A_obj = f.__closure__[1].cell_contents`
2. How can I access the properties `self.x`, `self.y` outside of the class? `A_obj.x, A_obj.y`

If you are on Python 3.8+ you can use `:=` and avoid dunders and cells.

You can decorate like so

```
@(a := A(1, 2)) # this assigns the object to `a`
def f():
    print('fun')

print(a is f.__closure__[1].cell_contents) # True
```

Which is pretty much this

```
a=A(1, 2)

@a
def f():
    print('fun')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attributes directly on the function, if you like:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper():
            print("decorated", self.x, self.y)
            func()
        wrapper.x = self.x
        wrapper.y = self.y
        wrapper.decorator = self
        return wrapper

@A(4, 5)
def fn():
    pass

print(fn.x, fn.y, fn.decorator)
```

which gives the output:

```
laurel% python3 ~/tmp/dec.py
4 5 <__main__.A object at 0x7f79ebb2cfd0>
laurel%
```